# Modeling many-to-many on the orders table

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am modeling a entity schema and I am not positive if the way I made the many-to-many relationship is the most efficient in my situation. The business requirement is to have compound orders. In order to be flexible, I need a many to many relationship between orders (as opposed to just creating a one-to-many by sticking **`ParentId`** on **`Order`** table).

I decided to add the **`CompoundOrder`** table to support the many-to-many relationship. 
Is this the only way to model this type of situation and is it most efficient?

Here is an example:

[image: My Model]

Answer (score 1):

That's not the standard way to do it. The standard way is for a Sales Order to have many Line Items.

```
SALES_ORDER
id
order_date
vendor_party_id
customer_party_id
bill_to_party_id
bill_to_address_id

ORDER_ITEM
id
order_id 
product_id
quantity
unit_price
ship_to_party_id
ship_to_address_id
```

Comment: In my case a compound order may contain N amount of children compound orders. In the Customer->Order->OrderLine->Product I dont think this is possible. Am I correct?